# Error when using mouseover div show message

Tags: javascript

```
var hello = document.createElement('<div>HELLO</div>');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].appendChild(hello);

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseMove, false);
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].removeChild(hello);
   wrapper .removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseMove, false);
}, 10000);

<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

When I moveover on  `<div id="wrapper"></div>`  is result null

How to when I moveover `<div id="wrapper"></div>` is result show `HELLO` in 10s, how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

function createHelloDiv() {
    var hello = document.createElement('div');
    var helloContents = document.createTextNode('hello');
    hello.appendChild(helloContents);
    return hello;
}

function onMouseOver() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        wrapper.appendChild(createHelloDiv());
        wrapper.removeEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver, false);
    }, 10000);
}

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver, false);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htz3j/3/) for working example.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achive ?

this part of code

```
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseMove, false);
```

binds mouse overevent to function mouseMove , that isn't exists in your context.

add

```
function mouseMove()
{
  alert();
}
```

This will not give you null...

In second case , please explain what you want to achieve ?